# How to interpret cross correlation matrix of time series

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, cross-correlation

I have made a cross-correlation matrix between the actual time series, the forecasted time series, and their lagged values. I need help in interpreting the results I can see from such a matrix. Specifically, I would like to know if my forecast model actually "learns" the underlying relation in the actual time series or if it just copies the values from the previous steps.

[image]

From my understanding, the predicted value at time t is highly correlated with the actual value at time t and then with the actual value of t-1 thus the model has "learned" some relations of the actual values.

Though when I am plotting some of the actual and forecasted values, forecasts(orange line) seem to be a lagged version of the actual values (blue line), which essentially means the model predicts that value at time t is more likely to be close to time t-1.
[image]

[image]

As for accuracy metrics, I have satisfying results for the current validation set. Low MAPE, MSE etc

So my question is, how to identify if my model has learned the underlying relationships in actual data or if it has just learned how to follow a trend with regards to a cross-correlation matrix. Or is cross-correlation the proper way to make that check.

Comment: In addition to validating your model, you can use a baseline and see if it performs better than that.

There are plenty of them but here is an example:
You already know that X_T(N) = X_T(N+1) + delta. So one naive way of forecasting tomorrow's value is to say it is going to be the same as today...

You can also use (weigetd) mean value of past few observations, flipping coins, purely random, linear autoregressoion and so on and so forth to validate your model agains those.